# AWS Cognito delete users with particular domain from a user pool

Tags: amazon-cognito

We have users in cognito with a particular domain that we would like to delete : @mailinator.com

Using AWS CLI in windows, I was going thru the api but I dont see any documentation around using regex to filter out the users from cognito.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have chance/env. to test it, but maybe you could give it a try with, just for example:

```
aws cognito-idp list-users --user-pool-id  us-west-demo --query "Users[?contains(not_null(Username,''),'@mailinator.com')]"
```

And if contains not working , try ends_with also,
make reference to [jmespath](https://jmespath.org/specification.html)